# [Lubuntu]Problem with installation (Grub?)

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

I was formatting my laptop as usual which had 4 operative systems (windows 7, kubuntu, kali and ubuntu) cause I wanted to delete everything and install only Windows 7 so, entered to the live installation of Windows 7 I deleted all the partitions and yes, maybe this caused some issue cause on then Windows 7 failed the installation and I ended up by having no OS...

Now after checked that this laptop has only 2GB of Ram I want to install Lubuntu and maybe in future Windows 7.

Booting the .iso from a USB device I get some troubles during the installation:
[image: failed installation of grub-pc]
after that error, this shows up:
[image: choose device for bootloader]
which even if choose one of them wont let me continue...

Here is more info: http:// paste2.org /xeJUnsUm (without space)

Comment: 2Gb RAM is good enough for Windows7 to run. While installing Windows7, at the disk partitions menu, first delete all partitions one by one, then create new partitions and install. It will work, I did it a lot of time.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee: i tried to delete all of them but it didnt work, maybe the DVD was damaged, anyway now i want to install Lubuntu also cause i dont have any DVD at the moment

Comment: All the best friend